# Washing Machine super loud noise at the start

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

I currently have front loader washing machine(samsung WF-JT254) and suddenly it started to start making super loud noise when I use it. I tried to record the sound I am getting when I record it on my phone, though its much much louder for real compared to watchin it on a video

https://streamable.com/vgwuid

I would like to seek advice on what should I do with it, I am planning to hire a guy to fix but I need to get your thought if its worth fixing or better to buy a new one. But when I tested it, I think its still usable the only problem is the noise. Note when I tried 'drain' it did the same loud noise.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the pump stalling because it has a sock stuck in it.
IF you feel competent to look up 'how to remove back from xyz appliance' and do it, you can.
The worst that happens is water on the floor and you started the job for the tech.
Remember to unplug before you start.

If you're not mechanically able then **don't use it** and wait for the tech.
Loud noises mean something is hitting/impinging where it shouldn't.

This is 'homeowner experience' not 'repair tech knowledge,' FWIW